# Matplotlib animation: setting fps=90 creates a movie file properly, but setting fps=120 does not?

Tags: animation, video, matplotlib, avi

Could you help me understand why this might be the case? This is what my command looks like:

```
ani.save("animation.avi", codec="libx264", fps=120)
```

The movie file size with the above command is very small in the order of hundreds of kilobytes. Playing the movie just shows a static picture (the very first frame).

```
ani.save("animation.avi", codec="libx264", fps=90)
```

This on the other hand, creates a movie file with a reasonable size in the order of megabytes, and plays as an animation as well.

At first, I thought this was an issue with a specific writer (avconv), but this problem occurs even when I have no writer specified, so it might be a general issue with my specific case, or matplotlib.