# Matplotlib animation: how do I increase the "rate at which time passes" in an animation?

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

The obvious answer to this question would be "change the framerate". [I can't seem to change the framerate beyond ~90 fps in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088468/matplotlib-animation-setting-fps-90-creates-a-movie-file-properly-but-setting). Thus, my question: given a fixed framerate, how can I increase the rate at which time passes in a movie?

For example, if I have `X` frames, where each frame represents the passage of 0.5 seconds in real time, then a framerate of 2 fps would play the movie in "real time". 90 fps would then be 45x faster than real time. What if I want to play the movie 90x faster than real time? What could I do?

Comment: Skip the alternative frames :P